# jQueryUI Dialog integration with standard form validation plugin; Best Practice/How-to?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'd like to add basic form validation to a UI Dialog using the standard.. http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/
Where this call works elsewhere (I can't make it work within a Dialog)..
    $("#FY12-Q1-AM-ALL-ECMC-VML-ProfilingForm").validate();

The Dialog Submit doesn't seem to catch the validation.. What approach have you guys used to solve the problem? I figure it must be a fairly common one -

thanks

```
$('#lowValueSurvey').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                width: 900,
                resizable: false,
                show:"puff",
                hide:"puff",
                close:"puff",
                open: function(event, ui) {
                    performElqLookups('#FY12-Q1-AM-ALL-ECMC-VML-ProfilingForm');
                },
                buttons: {
                    'Submit': function() {
                        $("#FY12-Q1-AM-ALL-ECMC-VML-ProfilingForm").validate();
                        $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    async: false,
                                    url:  $("#FY12-Q1-AM-ALL-ECMC-VML-ProfilingForm").attr('action'),
                                    data: $("#FY12-Q1-AM-ALL-ECMC-VML-ProfilingForm").serialize()
                                });
                        setCookie(lowValueCookieName, -1, 1000);
                        $(":button:contains('Submit')").hide();
                        $("#lowValueSurvey").load('/longstoryshort/forms/confirmation.html');
                        $("#lowValueSurvey").dialog({
                                    close: {effect: "fadeOut", duration: 5000}
                                });
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe validate only initializes the validation. You have to call .valid() to check for validation. You could try doing return false; to stop the function propagation if .valid() returns false.